# How to generate PFX file for Wild Card SSL Certificate using Openssl Command in Linux

Tags: linux, openssl, wildcard, pfx

I want to generate PFX file for my Wild Card SSL Certificate. I am using below mentioned command to generate the same however getting error message:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ./star_domain_com.pfx -inkey ./star.domain.com_CSR_Private_Key.key -in ./STAR.DOMAIN.COM.crt -in ./OV_USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt -in ./OV_XYZCompanyOVServerCA2.crt
No certificate matches private key
```

In the above command Key file has CSR as well as Private Key.

I tried using only Private Key as well however the results are same:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ./star_domain_com.pfx -inkey ./star.domain.comPrivate_Key.key -in ./STAR.DOMAIN.COM.crt -in ./OV_USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt -in ./OV_XYZCompanyOVServerCA2.crt
No certificate matches private key
```

I did check the Key using following command and both the files looks good:

```
openssl rsa -in star.domain.comPriveteKey.key -check
```

```
openssl rsa -in star.domain.com_CSR_Private_Key.key -check
```

I am not sure what needs to be fixed in this case as I am new to SSL Cert, seeking help from the community.

I would also like to know the meaning of these three SSL Certificate files:

- STAR.DOMAIN.COM.crt

  OV_USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt

  OV_XYZCompanyOVServerCA2.crt

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: I could generate the PFX File using below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971464/how-to-convert-crt-cetificate-file-to-pfx